# How to sum +1 if value exists

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

Hard to explain and english is not my native language, but i'll do my best. I have a cell with a CONCATENATE formula which creates a "code" value to identify different articles. The CONCATENATE formula is getting the values from 6 different cells. I need the 6th cell to sum +1 if the value of the other 5 cells already exist.

For example:

1
AAA

2
BBB

3
CCC

4
DDD

5
EEE

6
NNN (where NNN is a specific 3 characters number)

CONCATENATE creates the AAABBBCCCDDDEEENNN code. For the first article, it will be AAABBBCCCDDDEEE001. Then, if I create another article with AAABBBCCCDDDEEE, I want to 6th cell to fill up with 002, since 001 already exists.

Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something with [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34) or [SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)?

Comment: Put your formula in the question...

Comment: https://ibb.co/bXTLS5

As you can see in that link, the first "Code" column is getting the values from columns 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and #. First 5 columns value is gathered from another cells in the document. I want the # cell to be filled automatically like that example (which has been filled manually).

So, if you see at the last two rows, CHRFU15ALOR001 exists, then I had to manually type 002 in the next article with the same "CHRFU15ALOR" value. I want a formula to verify that CHRFU15ALOR001 exists and then put 002.

Comment: =CONCATENATE([@1];[@2];[@3];[@4];[@5];TEXT([@['#]];"000"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you enter '001 for the first cell in your 6th column, you can use this formula in the cell below it and copy it for all the cells below.

```
=IF(CONCATENATE(B2,C2,D2,E2,F2)=CONCATENATE(B1,C1,D1,E1,F1),CONCATENATE("00",G1+1),"001")
```

Comment: That seems to fit! I'll be doing some testing. Thanks!

Comment: This will only work for cases where the rows with equal values are together in a sequence, one after other. If the values of the fifth row are equal to the ones of the first row, it will not work.

Comment: Exactly, Dalton. I'm trying to figure out how the keep them in a sequence. Not the best way, but not sure if there is any other alternative.